# password is not getting applied when i protect sheet

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am using Excel API's to protect an Excel Sheet. I tried to do as they have mentioned in the documentation, but the Sheet is not protected by a password. It is simply getting protected without a password.

The code I am trying is as follow:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3").format.protection.locked = false;
    sheet.protection.protect({
        allowInsertRows: true
    }, "mypassword");
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

What is going wrong that password is not getting applied ?

Comment: Should the "locked" be set to true? I see it being set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually doing the opposite of what you want here. When you set `allowInsertRows: true` you are *unprotecting* row insertion. Since you're not protecting anything, the password you provided is simply ignored.

You need to set `allowInsertRows: false` to disable the ability to insert rows. Once this happens, the user will need to provide a password to unprotect the sheet:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    sheet.protection.protect({
        allowInsertRows: false
    }, "mypassword");
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

As an aside, this line is entirely unused and wouldn't work regardless. The `locked` property is Read-Only:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3").format.protection.locked = false;
```

---

Update: I just noticed the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetprotection) contains this sample (which clearly is where you got your code from):

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3").format.protection.locked = false;
    sheet.protection.protect({
        allowInsertRows: true
    });
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

This sample is wrong on several of levels. I'll make sure the sample gets updated ASAP. I'm sorry for the confusion this resulted in.

Comment: I used the same code that you given above making { allowInsertRows: false } but is still not giving expected result.